# incompatible types in assignment of 'void*' to 'char"------ in malloc

Tags: c++, malloc, type-conversion

I am using an ide dev-cpp. When I try to execute my program

```
char *path;
path = malloc(10);
```

this code is returning an error:

> 34 20 E:\C\dir.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

What is the reason?

how can I dynamically allocate memory for a char array?

Comment: you can write: `path = (char*) malloc(10);`

Comment: You're using a C++ compiler, not C compiler. What language are you actually using?

Comment: The reason is that you're lying. You claim this is C, but your code seems to be C++. You should decide which language you want to program in, ideally *before* you start writing code.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Wrong answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see no C++. This code is C, but OP thinks that it's possible (or a good idea) to compile C code using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3: And to call the file `dir.cpp`...?!

Comment: thats true i am actually using a c++ compiler

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, exactly. He thinks that C is a subset of C++.

Comment: @JimBalter actually not wrong you can ignar type cast in C, but OP is compiling as cpp. notice the extension of file of code. In cpp we shouldn't ignore typecast else error as OP got.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan And still, one should not typecast. If you need a cast, that indicates that something is wrong. In C++, one should either use `std::string` for strings, or if one uses raw pointers (which one shouldn't...), then the type-correct `new` should be preferred to `malloc()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 hmm That is Correct :), if one is using c++, use ++'s operators.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Actually truly and genuinely wrong for reasons explained all over this page. Note that someone gave your answer as an answer and rightly got downvoted. Note that when I wrote "wrong answer", I didn't mean that isn't valid C++ ... I'm of course aware of all the things you wrote.

Comment: @JimBalter Jim I came to this page for just few seconds so I didn't notice any answer. :) yes I noticed Pranaysharma's answer down voted (as I can see deleted posts) that is correct in C++.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan A lot got written between your comment and my noting that it is the wrong answer. And yes, we all know that it is *legal* C++ ... which does not mean that it's "correct".

Comment: @JimBalter btw this is second or third time you are correcting me Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had originally tagged this as C, but the file extension of your source file `dir.cpp` suggests that you're trying to write C++. If you intend to write C++, then you shouldn't be using `malloc` at all. Use `std::string` and allocate memory using `new`.

If for some reason you **must** use a C++ compiler to compile C, then you have to cast the returned pointer from `malloc` explicitly:

`path = (char*) malloc (10);`.

However, you'd be better advised to decide which language you want to work in. Either write straight-up C++, or use a C compiler for C code. Trying to use a C++ compiler will result in bogus warnings of this nature, and getting around those warnings will cause your C code to become pretty ugly and non-C like, as in the present instance.

Comment: And use `std::string` in C++.

Comment: <sigh> That's not how to cast in C++. In C++ you don't use `malloc`, you use `new`. In C++ you avoid using raw pointers. In C++, you don't use C strings, you use `std::string`. Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: David, you're right of course. This was originally tagged `C` (subsequently removed), and I assumed the OP was trying to write C code. I've edited my answer to remove that assumption. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You *can* use `malloc`, C-style strings, raw pointers, and C-style casts in C++; they're all perfectly legal. But C++ provides alternatives that are generally better *for C++ code* (though lower-level constructs might be appropriate, even in C++, if performance is critical (and *measured*)).

Answer (score 3):

You are compiling with a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler as would be suggested by the C tag to the question. Indeed, the compiler name, and your file name back up the fact that you are using a C++ compiler.

Your code is valid in C, but not valid in C++. In C++ you would need to cast the value returned by `malloc`. For a lengthy discussion of this difference between C and C++, I refer you to this article by Eli Bendersky: [void* and casts, in C and C++](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/16/void-and-casts-in-c-and-c/).

However, if you are writing C++ then you would avoid typically avoid `malloc` and raw pointers, and use `std::string` instead.

Alternatively, if you are writing C then you simply need to compile the code with a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Change the compiler you use for your code in dev-cpp

1. go to dev-cpp menu -> Project -> Project Options -> files tab
2. select file with your code
3. uncheck the `Compile file as C++`

Dev-cpp version 4.9.9.2.

Comment: Don't suggest #2. The C++ way is using `std::string`. An explicit cast of `malloc()` is considered a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns a void pointer to the memory allocated.
Since you are compiling using a C++ compiler, where strong type checking is done, this throws an error.
Typecasting it will solve your problem.

`path = (char * ) malloc (10);`
will work.

Also, instead of using a number like 10, use sizeof operator, like,

`path = (char *) malloc (10 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: typecasting will not solve the problem, it will only hide it. also, the use of the `sizeof` operator is redundant - `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1. My point was not about char.. i meant it to be generic.. as a coding practice. And since the code written is in C and not in C++, but compiled in C++ compiler, this is a sure shot way to get around the problem. Else, in CPP one should use string, new operator and other related stuff.